# Only setTimeout executes function. JS

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I am trying to implement kind of player on my website.
If press `'Play'` button, the music starts and the page smoothly scrolls down. 
But when you press `'Mute'` button `(function(){music.volume=0})` I am not sure why the page appears at the top again. `window.scroll()` doesn't do anything without delay. So i am using `setTimeout` function to scroll the page on the current place. The problem is that in Opera and IE `setTimeout` takes about `10 ms`, so when i click `'Mute'` button i see like ticks to top and back. In chrome it takes only `2 ms` and there is no problems.
Now when i decide to create my own timeout function the `window.scroll()` does not work again.

Here is my code:

```
var isMuted = false;
muteButton.onclick = function() {   ////This function works with big delay.
    if (!isMuted) {
        mainAudio.volume = 0;
        isMuted = true;
    } else {
        mainAudio.volume = bgAudioTrackVolume;
        isMuted = false;
    }
    setTimeout(function() {
        window.scroll(0, offset); /// Works
    }, 0)
};
```

Change setTimeout with:

```
i = 9542155.873; /// I have tried delay time from 1ms - 250ms by changing this value.
while (i > 0.00001) {
    i = i / 1.0001234567;
    if (i < 0.00001) {
        window.scroll(0, offset); /// Does not do anything. Strange! Have tried to change variable with a number.
    }
}
```

Every time i check offset value, it is always available before calling scroll function.
I know that my problem is not usual and i am realy need your help.

Comment: That's because your while loop is blocking, and setTimeout is non-blocking, so something in your script changes something, and using a setTimeout delays the execution until after those changes are made, as the script continues executing and just queues the timeout function for later, while the loop simply blocks the browser and the normal chain of execution is still in play.

Comment: What is the value of `offset` and how is it calculated?

Comment: Let me guess, the mute button looks like `<a href="#">` and you don't cancel the event?

Comment: Is `muteBUtton` a link? With a `href="#"` attribute?

Comment: Yes it is a link! Is that a problem? Should i change it with a label?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that the page scrolls to the top is that you are using a link with the empty bookmark `#`, which represents the top of the page. The reason that the `scroll` method doesn't work without a timeout is that jumping to the bookmark happens after the event handler.

Instead of trying to scroll the page back to where it was, just stop the default action of the link by returning `false` from the event handler:

```
var isMuted = false;
muteButton.onclick = function() {
    if (!isMuted) {
        mainAudio.volume = 0;
        isMuted = true;
    } else {
        mainAudio.volume = bgAudioTrackVolume;
        isMuted = false;
    }
    return false;
};
```

Alternatively, use some other element than a link.